# angular crud dialog one generic or unique

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-modal

I started to build an AngularJs app. I have many dialogs with add\edit operations. My question is should I build functions/controllers/services for each one of the operations but have the same html just with different handlers? Or should I do it in generic way (and with many if-cases)? what is the cost for the first option?